# Using Blobstore Python API over HTTPS generates 405 error when redirecting back

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Don't know if it's I'm doing it wrong or if there's a bug (I would think so, seen others having the same problem) in the `blobstore.create_upload_url` method.

In my app.yaml I have for some url's the property `secure: always` and the `action` attribute of the `form` element starts with `https://` but when it's return from the API it's redirected to non-https.

There's a bug file on [google app engine issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=3463) but no response from google.

Does anyone know of a good work around? My current solution is to have a separate .py file to handle the response and then direct back to the original url but over https.

**EDIT**

I use this to set the action attribute:

```
from google.appengine.api import blobstore
view['upload_url'] = blobstore.create_upload_url 
## pass the view dict to template and in template

<form action="{{ upload_url }}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
</form>
```

The output in the html looks something like:

```
action="https://appid.appspot.com/_ah/upload/AMmfu6bcA9Sfz5isqw6PNNB8xzRy2rUoLaMS2GFjfPEwCZ-vg9M_hQTOR87wYdnMo7ZIbQX9NiNjORFTiKaUoLMHRpXvPf6r8Y5963GD9Cbv_9gIKgtEmtdvt5VcvQxzvbegqG3V5xQT/ALBNUaYAAAAATPdfcxxACFrQnUiLXWx61ViMDZ7F0aLF/"
```

The file uploads (I can view it in admin console->blob viewer) but when the API redirect back it redirects http and when using `secure: always` a http request returns a HTTP 405 error.

This is the upload handler:

```
class AddUpdateImageStore(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler):
def post(self):
    if self.request.get('imagestore_key'):
        image = dbImageStore.ImageStore.get(self.request.get('imagestore_key'))
    else:
        image = dbImageStore.ImageStore()

    image.name = self.request.get('image_name')

    upload_files =  self.get_uploads('image_file')

    if upload_files:
        image.imageUrl = images.get_serving_url(str(upload_files[0].key()))

    imageKey = db.put(image)

    for language in Settings.languages:
        description = self.request.get('image_description_' + language)
        if description:
            imageDescription = dbImageStore.ImageDescription.gql('WHERE imageEntry = :imageEntry AND lang = :lang', imageEntry = imageKey, lang = language).get()
            if imageDescription is None:
                imageDescription = dbImageStore.ImageDescription()
                imageDescription.imageEntry = imageKey
                imageDescription.lang = language

            imageDescription.description = description
            db.put(imageDescription)

    self.redirect('/edit/imageStore/?status=1&message=Image added/updated')
```

Comment: Need to see your upload-handling code, too.

Comment: @nick updated the code with the upload handler

Comment: Is /edit/imagestore/ mapped to AddUpdateImageStore? Does it have a get() method?

Comment: Yes it's mapped to AddUpdateImageStore and has no get methods. Only post. I followed this in the docs: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview.html Should it have an get handler too?

Comment: Er, yes. When you send a redirect, the browser fetches the target URL with a GET request. If you don't have a get() method, the framework will return 405.

Comment: Oh sorry, I miss read your previous comment. '/edit/imagestore/' is mapped to another webapp handler that has a get method. Sorry about that. Could it be that `self.redirect` for some reason doesn't redirect to https?

Comment: Any luck with this? I am having a similar problem and am starting to think the Blobstore API will not work over HTTPS. If you put a get() method on your AddUpdateImageStore handler you will see that it gets called instead of the POST method when the Blobstore redirects after the file is uploaded. I am trying to solve this by having just the file upload portion of my app run over HTTP but this is NOT what I want in the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue has been fixed by SDK 1.4.2. I just tested it and it is working fine now.

See issue in tracker here:
http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=3463

Comment: No problem. SDK 1.4.2 was recently released on Feb 10, 2011.